# Fuse ESB admin command not found

Tags: fuseesb, fusefabric

I use jboss fuse 6.0.0 in windows and start the container using the `bin/fuse.bat`. The `etc/users.properties` is modified to add the line `admin=admin,admin`.

At first the `admin` command acts as normal. I have `admin:list` showing all the containers, `admin:create` to create the child containers.

Then I followed the instructions of

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Getting_Started/files/Deploy-Fabric-Create.html

and create a fabric use the command `fabric:create --clean`. After that the `admin` command is gone! I get `Command not found: admin:list`, and I can no longer list the child containers created by `admin:create`. The `fabric:container-list` command only enumerates the containers created by the `fabric:container-create-child` command.

Does any one experienced this problem before? Is it normal? How can I get the `admin` commands back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected, when you create fabric, then fabric is managing the containers. So you should use fabric commands to create/manage your containers.

Comment: okay, that makes me feel safe. Learning to use Fuse ESB is not easy.